# Rails SQL: How to search on a column in a table ignoring all special characters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

I am searching for matching values in MyTable.

```
name to search for -> This-is-a (test/with/time)
The name from DB table -> "this-is-a-test-with/time"
```

If I can get both the column value and the search value to match on something like this -> `"thisisatestwithtime"` which ignores all special characters and spaces.

```
value = This-is-a (test/with/time)
MyTable.where("upper(name) = upper(?)",value.to_s.scan(/[0-9a-z]/i).join("")).first
```

This converts the value to a form where all special characters are removed but how can I run the same on the value is in the table?

Comment: Would you expect that a search for `a-b` finds `ab-cd` because without the `-` it would search for `ab` and match `abcd`? Or should `a-b` only find strings like `a-b-cd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression search.

```
select * from "table" where "name" ~ 'this' and name ~ 'is' and name ~ 'a' 
and name ~ 'test' and name ~ 'with' and name ~ 'time';
```

If you want to search whole words only (for example find `-a-` instead of `cat`)

```
name ~ '\ma\M'
```

For case insensitive, use

```
name ~* 'a'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

You can also use `replace` to match the whole values

```
select * from table where regex_replace(name, '\W', '') = :name

Table.where("regex_replace(name, '\W', '') = :name", name: 'thisisatestwithtime')
```